# Copying static files and directories from an adjacent maven module using resources plugin?

Tags: java, maven

I have an adjacent module to my current module and want to pull in a directory with its children from the adjacent module and copy the contents to the target directory when building my current module.

I am wondering the best way to get the relative path to the adjacent guy in the directory directive.

## Attempt

````
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-resources</id>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <resources>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>../adjacent/src/main/docker/</directory>
                                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/*</include>
                                            </includes>
                                            <excludes>
                                                <exclude>**/nodes/**</exclude>
                                                <exclude>**/data/**</exclude>
                                            </excludes>
                                        </resource>
                                        <resource>
                                            <directory>../adjacent/src/main/docker/</directory>
                                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                                            <includes>
                                                <include>**/data/**</include>
                                            </includes>
                                        </resource>
                                    </resources>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to declare an execution of the `maven-resources-plugin` explicitely. It can be achieved, simplifying the POM, within the [`default-resources`](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Resources) execution, as well:

```
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>

      <resource>
        <targetPath>..</targetPath>  <!--  relative to the target/classes directory
                                           (i.e. ${project.build.outputDirectory}) -->
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>

      <resource>
        <targetPath>..</targetPath>
        <directory>../adjacent/src/main/docker/</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/nodes/**</exclude>
          <exclude>**/data/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>

      <resource>
        <targetPath>..</targetPath>
        <directory>../adjacent/src/main/docker/</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
          <include>**/data/**</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>

    </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

For `<directory>` "[*The path is relative to the POM.*](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.0/maven-model/maven.html#class_resource)". So, `../adjacent/src/...` is OK.

This has also the advantage that these declarations are considered by the Eclipse m2e plugin, i.e. the resources are copied at a *Project* → *Clean...* rather than during a Maven build only.